# UIView bottom to top animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

This is a simple function I am using for animating a view from top to bottom and vice versa (if is top to bottom animation and else is bottom to top animation) :

```
@objc func openMenu(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            self.buttonView.tag = 2
             self.moduleView = ModulesCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height + 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())
            self.window?.addSubview(self.moduleView)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                self.moduleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height + 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - self.frame.size.height - 22)
            }, completion: { _ in

            })

        } else {
            self.buttonView.tag = 1
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 3, animations: {
                self.moduleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height + 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 0)
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.moduleView.removeFromSuperview()
            })
        }
    }
```

Top animation works fine and the view is animated from top to bottom pleasantly in 0.7 seconds. However, bottom to top animation does not happen. The view is removed instantly. This is the result I am getting :

[image]

But I want the animation to be clean while going from bottom to top as well. Just like [**here**](https://github.com/younatics/YNDropDownMenu).

**Secondary :** What I finally plan to achieve is [**PullUpController**](https://github.com/MarioIannotta/PullUpController) with the exact reverse animation. So if anyone knows a similar library (pull down drag) can share there inputs.

**Update** : *The issue is coming only with UICollectionView. I replaced collectionView with a simple UIView and it worked perfect.*

Comment: what was the frame before animation starts

Comment: you also need to state the frame before animation like you done in if part you also have do in else part

Comment: @sanjaykmwt : I don't think so.

Comment: You are trying to move an object from the bottom of the view to the top of the view and animate it yeah? why do you keep the Y value the same? why are you animating height to 0?

Comment: @Scriptable : That is because the view is added on window and does not start from 0. It starts from bottom of navigation bar

Comment: yes when going from top to bottom. but thats not the issue is it, its when going from bottom to top? so surely it needs to start from the bottom and move to 0,0 (the top). if it starts at the bottom (frame.height) and you **add** to the Y value it will go further bottom and go off the screen

Comment: I added a playground, where the view moves to the bottom and then back to the top.

Comment: @Krunal : Added

Comment: @Krunal : Did that. Changes the height to 100 but without animation

Comment: set 0.7 duration instead 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use `layoutSubViews()` method after at the end of animation block. Change the animation block like this.

For if block:

```
self.moduleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height + 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - self.frame.size.height - 22)
self.moduleView.layoutSubviews()
```

For else block:

```
self.moduleView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: self.frame.origin.y + self.frame.size.height + 20, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 0)
self.moduleView.layoutSubviews()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is example code, hope it will help.

Show view:

```
self.containerView = ModulesCollectionView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
self.containerView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x,
        y: self.view.center.y + self.view.frame.size.height)
self.window?.addSubview(self.moduleView)
self.window?.bringSubview(toFront: self.moduleView)
self.window?.endEditing(true)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, delay: 0.0,
    usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 3.0,
    options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
    self.moduleView.center = self.view.center
}) { (isFinished) in
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

hide view:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, delay: 0.0,
    usingSpringWithDamping: 1, initialSpringVelocity: 1.0,
    options: .allowAnimatedContent, animations: {
    self.moduleView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.center.x,
    y: self.view.center.y + self.view.frame.size.height)
}) { (isFinished) in
    self.moduleView.removeFromSuperview
}
```

Comment: What would be the initial frames I need to set for this to work ?

Comment: For example if you want it to cover whole screen, you can set it like this `self.moduleView = ModulesCollectionView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)`. Adjust it to what you need

Comment: My class is a subclass of UIView. So I am not sure why you are using self.view.center..... Is this a copied code or are you sure this works ?

Comment: How could I know that your class is subclass of UIView? :) This code demonstrated how to show/hide view with animation. You can adjust it for your needs

Comment: The issue is coming with UICollectionView. Please check my updated question.