# UICollectionView show hide animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, ios-animations

I am getting animation issue while hiding the `UICollectionView`. Show animation works fine but when I do the hide animation, it immediately hides the collection view without animation. This is the code :

```
@objc func openMenu(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            self.buttonView.tag = 2
            self.arrow.image = UIImage(named: "arrowUp.png")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                self.moduleView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - self.frame.size.height
            }, completion: { _ in
            })
        } else {
            self.buttonView.tag = 1
            self.arrow.image = UIImage(named: "arrowDown.png")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                self.moduleView.frame.size.height = 0
            }, completion: { _ in
            })
        }
    }
```

**Output :**

[image]

The strange thing is, I replaced the collection view with a simple `UIView` and it works fine. Bottom to top animation works perfectly. Code :

```
@objc func openMenu(sender: UIButton) {
        if sender.tag == 1 {
            self.buttonView.tag = 2
            self.arrow.image = UIImage(named: "arrowUp.png")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                self.testView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - self.frame.size.height
            }, completion: { _ in
            })
        } else {
            self.buttonView.tag = 1
            self.arrow.image = UIImage(named: "arrowDown.png")
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                self.testView.frame.size.height = 0
            }, completion: { _ in
            })
        }
    }
```

**Output :**

[image]

**Question** : Why doesn't that work for **UICollectionView** ?

**Initialisation :**

**UICollectionView :**

```
self.moduleView = ModulesCollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 0), collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout())  
self.parentView.addSubView(self.moduleView)
```

**UIView :**

```
self.testView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 0))  
self.parentView.addSubView(self.testView)
```

Comment: Just provide background color to collectionview / cell and check what is happening

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya Same effect. Like I said, collection view dismisses quickly

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya : Sorry. I was wrong earlier. I put a collared background on collectionView. Saw that collectionView dismisses correctly. But the content (items) inside it disappears quickly

Comment: I think issue might be when collection view bounds changes then cell might trying to adjust according to it. do you have anything in layoutSubview's method ?

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya : Nopes. There's nothing in that

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya : Hold on. There is layoutSubview I have overridden in custom cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `layoutSubViews()` method for proper animation. Please change your code as below :

```
@objc func openMenu(sender: UIButton) {
    if sender.tag == 1 {
        self.buttonView.tag = 2
        self.arrow.image = UIImage(named: "arrowUp.png")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            self.moduleView.frame.size.height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height - self.frame.size.height
            // Add this line
            self.moduleView.layoutSubviews()
        }, completion: { _ in
        })
    } else {
        self.buttonView.tag = 1
        self.arrow.image = UIImage(named: "arrowDown.png")
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
            self.moduleView.frame.size.height = 0
            // Add this line
            self.moduleView.layoutSubviews()
        }, completion: { _ in
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Post this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50741078/uiview-bottom-to-top-animation-issue) as well which is a bounty